# Are there any "RLink" like projects, which enable the interaction between R and Mathematica?

Tags: interoperability, rlink

I want to borrow the vast amount of packages of R. I know [there was one](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6510/) but it is neither sold nor supported anymore. So are there any active open source projects for linking R with Mathematica? Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Erich Neuwirth on MathGroup](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/25804276514b4b0e/eab580f81d5b3339?lnk=raot) mentioned a solution for Windows (free for non-commercial applications) that you can download [here](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/).

Here is his example with small updates from Sasha and Mark Fisher. After downloading the R instalation and DCOM server stuff I tried it and it seems to work just fine.

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
myR = CreateCOMObject["StatConnectorSrv.StatConnector"]
myR@Init["R"]
myR@SetSymbol["xxx", 12321]
result1 = myR@GetSymbol["xxx"]
myR@EvaluateNoReturn["randmat<-matrix(rnorm(100),10)"]
rmat = myR@GetSymbol["randmat"]
result2 = myR@Evaluate["solve(matrix(1:4,2))"]

(*
==> NETLink`Objects`NETObject$3810539581$1070974657101825
*)

(*
==> 12321
*)

(*
==> {{-0.2729702674, 1.803861976, 0.5813040979, 0.1600081953, 
  0.7538751951, 0.3923246778, 1.240256949, 2.143071289, -0.2112634412,
   0.9417189228}, {-0.1815065752, 0.6340400316, 
  0.6235181836, -0.1729713552, -0.965223049, -0.8076688634, 
  0.6125102682, 0.8043927759, 
  0.2623272614, -0.7300377248}, {-0.1573784247, 
  1.745921499, -1.223295754, 
  0.7508255497, -1.437158433, -0.5431748169, 
  0.5224185732, -0.006148655396, -0.5381351892, -0.1264029232}, \
{-0.2285349193, 0.5978044841, 
  0.7099844671, -0.830220449, -0.5994523393, -0.1600179795, 
  0.2957343203, -0.2560352574, 
  1.45552903, -0.9763608981}, {-0.5509826168, 0.4205191323, 
  2.021672968, 0.4834619721, -0.6738896365, -1.782509979, 0.515151609,
   0.6698301759, -1.914440159, 0.1741606405}, {1.199489342, 
  1.397342011, -0.08762926484, 0.3572575699, 0.1415520058, 
  0.2384566775, -0.598134357, -0.199506724, -0.4849505361, 
  0.1238990228}, {0.55417032, 
  0.4911786903, -0.2432415953, -1.270176719, 
  0.3143047255, -0.3256634613, 0.9347990095, 
  0.6459510591, -0.924018154, 1.091294398}, {-0.5705422396, 
  0.1740525789, -0.7607604118, -0.4584603394, -2.602648464, \
-0.08879130709, 1.550124853, 0.4472847015, 0.1335582644, 
  0.07635818615}, {1.301494963, 1.106258178, 
  0.3354845242, -1.45468913, -0.3581930843, 
  1.187368824, -0.1503588385, 0.1511637701, 2.236312191, 
  1.067101554}, {0.04525815419, 0.1181913247, 
  1.588764281, -0.7367518216, -1.79115224, -3.891936361, 2.463525431, 
  2.721622641, 0.8049086131, -0.1488657311}}
*)

(*
==> {{-2., 1.5}, {1., -0.5}}
*)

myR@Close[]
```

Comment: I've got exceptions when executing myR@Init["R"]: NET::netexcptn: A .NET exception occurred: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Comment: @ziyuang I assume you did à successful full download and install of the above mentioned R system and DCom connector? For me, it worked as advertised.

Comment: I did not notice the warning from statconn's page, saying "...All the statconn tools (statconnDCOM, rcom, RExcel ..) work only with the 32bit version of R..." And everything is fine after I installed the i386 version of R.

Comment: Where can I get a full list of the methods (GetSymbol/SetSymbol/EvaluateNoReturn/...)?

Comment: @ziyuang If I study the installed documentation (see the stacon installation folder) it looks the above example basically shows all the methods.

Comment: Moreover, can I show R graphics in Mathematica's notebook (rather than in a new R graphics window)?

Comment: @ziyuang I saw somewhere on their website a question about R graphics is Excel. I suppose it should be possible, but really, I don't know more about RLink than you. I downloaded it to see it works and that's about it I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Sjoerd C. de Vries

Comment: Anything that connects R with Mathematica under Mac OS X?

Comment: @murray I'm sorry, the above is all that I know about this topic.

Answer (score 14):

Mathematica 9 includes an [RLink feature](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/tutorial/UsingRLink.html).

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that. Thank you~

Comment: I came too late :). +1

Comment: @LeonidShifrin like you need the reputation ... :)

Comment: @rcollyer Well, there is never enough :)

Comment: OK, here comes mine. (not that I use R, or ever would, but I am told the author of RLink in M9 is beyond brilliant.)