# Reading RData files without RLink

Tags: import, version-8, interoperability

I am using Mathematica 8. I would like to read some RData files which I have received. I do not currently have an installation of R on the machine with Mathematica.

Comment: @Szabolcs He has version 8.

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/844/are-there-any-rlink-like-projects-which-enable-the-interaction-between-r-and/1272#1272) may possibly help, if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without RLink, which is part of version 9 and is not available in version 8, the easiest way is probably to install R and export the data in a format that Mathematica can read.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189467/how-to-convert-rdata-format-into-text-file-format) should help you export the data from R.

Comment: I know that you asked for a solution without R, but I truly believe that the least effort solution is to install R and export in an alternate format.

Comment: I agree, this seems the easiest way.+1.